# Pass parameters with props in react native

Tags: react-native

I want to pass the clicked searchItem's id from my component. My code is as follows.

```
const searchResultList = props => (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always">
      {props.itemList.map(item => (
        <SearchResultListItem
          key={item.id}
          imageSource={item.workoutImage}
          mainText={item.workoutName}
          subText={item.length + " |  " + item.difficulty}
          onItemPressed={props.onItemPressed}
        />
      ))}
    </ScrollView>
  </View>
);
```

When, onItemPressed, i want to pass the item.id with the prop.onItemPressed. This is my screen.

```
<SearchResultList
     itemList={this.props.searchedWorkouts}
     onItemPressed={id => alert(item.id)} //this.onLoadWorkoutDetailView()}
/>
```

How can I achieve this? I want the clicked itemId to my main screen.

Comment: Do you want to navigate to other screen with some parameters?

Comment: I want to get the clicked items ID from the main screen.... <SearchResultList
     itemList={this.props.searchedWorkouts}
     onItemPressed={id => alert(item.id)} //this.onLoadWorkoutDetailView()}
/>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make an addition function. Straightforward it will be like this:

```
...
onItemPressed={() => props.onItemPressed(item.id)}
...
```

But, it`s not a good solution from performance point of view.

The better way is to make a method and bind all items to this method.

```
class SearchResultList extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    const {itemsList} = props;
    this._onPressHandlers = {};

    for (let {id} for itemsList) {
      this._onPressHandlers[id] = this._onItemPress.bind(this, id);
    }
  }

  _onItemPress(id) {
    return this.props.onItemPressed(id);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always">
          {props.itemList.map(item => (
            <SearchResultListItem
              key={item.id}
              imageSource={item.workoutImage}
              mainText={item.workoutName}
              subText={item.length + " |  " + item.difficulty}
              onItemPressed={this._onPressHandlers[item.id]}
            />
          ))}
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

In this case the handlers will not be generated on each render of list and will not cause re-render of `SearchResultListItem` component.

> Obviously, if you expect changes of the `itemsList` prop, you will need to rebind it on `componendWillReceiveProps` method.